# Deembeding S-parameters

Tags: pcb, rf, signal-processing, signal-integrity

I have a deembed S2P(S-parameter) file of the probe and output waveform of the probe. I need to get back the waveform at the probe point by passing the output waveform through the deembed S2P file.
Can someone let me know how to do the processing of the probe output waveform with the deembed S-parameter S2P file.(I am unable to do in MATLAB).
I have tried using the Keysight ADS tool but the tool is not simulating the above scenario in TRANSIENT SIM to get back the original signal.